# InvalidCastException trying to cast Object[] array to string array

Tags: c#

I have a method that takes an ArrayList object as a parameter.

I then try to convert this arrayList into a string array but get an InvalidCastException.

The ArrayList contains a seven random numbers. As they are of the type object I am assuming it shouldnt be a problem casting it into a string.

This is the method that I have called

```
p.matches(winningNumber);

public void matches(ArrayList al)
    {
        try
        {
            string nameFile;

            string[] winningNumber = (string[])al.ToArray(typeof(string));

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the name of the file you want to Read from");
            nameFile = Console.ReadLine();
```

it is with the attemt at casting that I get an exception.

Comment: Why aren't you using a generic `List<T>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this exception because in order to convert to array of strings, the elements themselves must be strings as well. You can do it with LINQ, though:

```
string[] winningNumber = al.Cast<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray();
```

To deal with `null`s, replace `o.ToString()` with `""+o` or a conditional that checks for `null`s.

Comment: It will fail for null values

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
string[] winningNumber = (string[])al.ToArray(typeof(string));
```

To

```
string[] winningNumber = al.Cast<object>.Select(x=> x==null ? string.Empty : x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

If you have some items that are not string, you  can use [Enumerable.OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx). It will ignore non string types.

```
string[] winningNumber = al.OfType<string>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] winningNumber = al.Cast<object>.Select(x=>Convert.ToString(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Enumerable.Select not available on ArrayList (as it is not generic)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use [**Enumerable.Cast**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) before you call ToArray

```
string[] winningNumber = al.Cast<string>().ToArray();
```

Comment: It will fail if there are non string values. If all are string values, OP solution will work.